# How do I make my FAQ more accessible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I have this question and answer format:

```js
$('.qanda button').click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.siblings('.answer').slideDown(function(){
        $(this).attr('tabindex', '-1').focus();
        btn.remove();
    });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0;}

.qanda {
    margin: 2em 0;
    clear: both;
}
.answer {
    display: none;
    clear: both;
    outline: none;
}
.qanda h2 {
    float: left;
}
.qanda button{
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="qanda">
    <h2>Is the sky blue?</h2>
    <button>+</button>
    <div class="answer">
        <p>That depends on various factors, including whether it's night or day.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsbin.com/jazekotosa/

I realise I haven't practised progressive enhancement in that the answers are hidden using static CSS. However, if I added this rule with JS and used this page for many questions, I'm assuming that on some devices the answers might display for a split second while the page loads. So I'm relying on JavaScript to be running (although I'm not sure that in itself is a barrier to accessibility).

When the answer reveal animation is complete, the focus is set to the displayed div, meaning screen readers will (in my limited experience) read from that point.

The buttons naturally take focus, so it seems keyboard accessible.

What else can I do?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. it's more about UX, which is essentially asking for opinions.

Comment: If the css that hides the answers is part of the page and is rendered before the affected element, that element should never appear event for a split second.  If that css is in a separate file, the element may appear before the css loads.

Comment: Thoroughly read the [Web Accessibility Initiative (WAI)](http://www.w3.org/WAI/).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to make this gracefully degrade is to have a snippet of code something like this:

```
<noscript><link rel=stylesheet src="no_js.css"></noscript>
```

and then have a CSS file `no_js.css` like so:

```
.answer {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

so that when scripting is turned off, that stylesheet *overrides* the original styles to make all `.answer`s visible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the CSS on a page depending on whether JavaScript is active, try to [avoid *noscript*](https://web.archive.org/web/20110828160000/http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/a/noscriptnomore.htm). Best practice seems to be adding JavaScript in the *head* to append the CSS to the DOM.

```
var fileref=document.createElement("link");
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href", "css/style2.css");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

Or in jQuery...

```
$('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css" />').appendTo('head');
```

As for what you can do for browsers without JavaScript, there are ways to manipulate the content using pure CSS. This fiddle uses focus, but tracking invisible checkboxes is also an alternative.

http://jsfiddle.net/x33kcr18

Or split the FAQ answers into their own HTML pages and load them dynamically using iFrames.

```
<h2>Is the sky blue?</h2>
<a href="answer1.html" target="answer1"><button>+</button></a>
<iframe name="answer1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

The current fashion seems to be to [offset the text from the screen](http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/).

However, bear in mind that screen readers [do support JavaScript](http://a11yproject.com/posts/myth-screen-readers-dont-use-javascript/).

Best thing to do is [try it out](http://www.nvaccess.org/download/), I guess.